# Gurobi optimizer (Python): Linearize quadratic constraint?

Tags: python-2.7, nonlinear-optimization, gurobi, quadratic-programming

Question: How I may linearize the following constraint (joined figure), where 
r[x][y], c[y,j], a[j,t] and p[x,t+l] are binary variables.

Could someone help me please ?

Best

Quadratic constraint

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can introduce an auxiliary binary variable `ap`, which holds the product of `a` and `p`.

Linearization can be done with:

```
ap <= a
ap <= p
ap >= a + p - 1
```

Then your remaining formula is ready to be formulated within gurobi (no more quadratic terms).